# How do I execute ransomware in a windows sandbox environment when the file is not an executable

Tags: memory, malware, computer-forensics

I have several malware repositories however I am unable to get bin files to execute or files as windows classifies them. I have included some file names so you can see what I'm working with. I have been trying to mount some of the files which are Bin files with no luck.
Tank_3d.jar
b0ffb939b3df60f8561fadf2cbfa1733_WEXTRACT.EXE_
userinit.exe with a `desktop.BIN`
why the extra file with the executable?
13ce4cd747e450a129d900e842315328 and windows says type of file is file?
Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated I have searched the web but I haven't found any sites that tell you how to execute these files for obvious reasons. I have changed some of the file extensions to .exe and some of them will execute in this manner. However, a lot of them still will not. I have conducted static analysis of these files prior to trying to do dynamic analysis. Also I forgot to add I'm doing this research for a university thank you

Answer (score 2):

The question is not completely clear to me but as I understood from what you said, you have some files (probably related to some malware/ransomware) that you don't know how to execute them.
Before just starting to execute a malware or whatever suspicious file, you need to collect as much information as possible about your files. This step is called information gathering. So this is what you need to do:
(these are optional steps and can be changed based on your experience)

1. Calculate the MD5 hash of the file then search the MD5 value in [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com) or [Hybrid-Analysis](https://hybrid-analysis.com/) to check if these engines already analyzed this sample or not.
   (or you can directly upload your sample to these engines without calculating the MD5 value)
2. Search on Google for whatever information you have about your file (even you can search the file name itself). You don't want to re-analyze the sample if someone already did that for you unless you are looking for some variants or some specific features. Even in that case, reading other related analysis report can help you do it faster.
3. Get the type of the file using whatever tool to extract the magic header (signature) of the file. I would say use [Linux file command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) but you can use other tools as well.
4. Try to open the file in a hex editor/display software (you can find lots of them if you search), to see if there is anything interesting in the file.
5. use [Linux Strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) or [Windows Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) commands to extract human-readable strings from the file to see what you can find.
6. Doing all the above mentioned steps, you will have the idea how you should deal with the file.
7. Use Peid or Die (Detect it easy) to extract the programming language and possible packer name/entropy of the file.
8. and finally, to execute different file formats:

   - If it's a .jar file: java -jar sample.jar
   - If it's a .dll file: use rundll32 or OllyDBG.
   - If you have an .exe file: just run it.

People who start learning malware analysis, they just try to execute the file or start with dynamic analysis but one needs to know that these steps are very helpful before executing the sample since most of the time you will get what you want from information gathering and static analysis.

If you explain better the problem, maybe people can help you better!

Edit:
I am going to add this part to the answer to cover the comments.

> why are there additional files in the malware folder like an executable with a bin file?

This is a simple trick which has been used by malware writers for several years. For example, in one scenario, the main file of the malware can be an executable file (.exe) but it's actually not harmful at all!!!. All it is doing is to download another file (e.g., .dll file) which is the real malicious code (you can call it the payload). However, sending and receiving .dll files is also suspicious, so malware authors use other file extensions or whatever to hide the malicious content (like .bin file or even .png file in one of the variants of Emotet). The problem is that you CAN NOT execute these files just like that! since sometimes there are encrypted/encoded.
You need to know the procedure of executing them which is only possible to know if you reverse engineer the sample.

for example:
13ce4cd747e450a129d900e842315328 -> .DLL file

This means you may be able to analyze it using Ollydbg or any debugger + rundll32 but there is no guarantee!! it may be encrypted or encoded and only the parent file (.exe sample for example) can decrypt/decode it!

> I am now interested in performing memory analysis of the malware which I possess. however the problem I encountered was how to execute a lot of the ransomware files I have to examine

I would say it would be nice to execute all of them using Win10 VM + cuckoo sandbox and dump the memory for further analysis. It's all automatic job and can be done nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful and thorough response. My problem is very detailed but you did give very detailed information. For starters I have run all of the samples through virustotal to determine if they have been detected and classified. Static analysis of the malware has been conducted and I am now interested in performing memory analysis of the malware which I possess. however the problem I encountered was how to execute a lot of the ransomware files I have to examine. I am executing them in a Windows 10 Pro Vm environment.

Comment: The issue though is for instance why are there additional files in the malware folder like an executable with a bin file? or for instance this specific instance of malware contains four files which are classified by windows as type= file how do I run them? 13ce4cd747e450a129d900e842315328, c2bb7a8316ef7a106e6a3b3bb8d5532a, cbe853d5d7ec089ef0302789284d6c44,e16261185c13fb16213288a3860c1b8d these are the files name and if they are run through virsutotal will return as authentic malware but how do I run them